# How to show the ant task javac compilation errors on console using Eclipse AntRunner

Tags: ant, eclipse-plugin

I'm using Elcipse's AntRunner to excute the Ant task. When performing the javac task,if any compilation error occurs, I'm getting the following error messge in the console

```
C:\build.xml:41: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

What I need to do for displaying the actual compilation errors on the console? How to I can log the same in a file? . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Eclipse AntRunner has used, in order to show the Compilation errors on the console The

*addBuildListener* API can be used.

Create a class which extends the org.apache.tools.ant.DefaultLogger. For example

```
Class MyLogger extends DefaultLogger {

    // All overridden method implementation goes here
  }

//  To use with AntRunner:

   AntRunner antRunner = new AntRunner();
   antRunner.addBuildListener(MyLogger.class.getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Ant eclipse plugin, but I think this could be caused by lack of feature within the plugin, not the Ant itself.

If you can run Ant from the terminal (or command prompt on windows), try run `ant -verbose` for Ant to output more information.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer,I'm not going to run the script thru cmd,but in the javac task I've set the verbose value as "true",that did not help.So I think from the plugin I'm missing something